# How do I explicitly whitelist the following parameters on my rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

This is the hash on the request:

```
{"a"=>{"foo"=>{"1"=>[{"bar"=>"1", "qaz"=>"80"}], "6"=>[{"bar"=>"1", "qaz"=>"80"}, {"bar"=>"1", "qaz"=>"84"}]}}
```

I've been trying something like this without luck:

```
params.require(:a).permit({foo: [:bar, :qaz]})
```

I get the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 6
```

Comment: Try giving `params.require(:a).permit(foo: [:bar, :qaz])` Not sure though. This `"6"=>[{"foo"=>"1", "qaz"=>"80"}` has a one more `foo` which is very confusing.How did you got that hash request?

Comment: Tried it, but got the same error. The "foo" was an error, I already corrected it on the original post. My form name attributes look something like this: name="a[foo][#{some_param}][][bar]" and name="a[foo][#{some_param}][][qaz]"

Comment: Post the `original parameters` that are generated.

Comment: Do you mean the original params request. Here they are:

`{"line_item"=>{"variant_id"=>"66", "product_additions"=>{"1"=>[{"quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"80"}], "6"=>[{"quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"80"}, {"quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"84"}]}}}`

Comment: And this is an example of the name attribute on the form: 

`name="line_item[product_additions][6][][product_id]"
name="line_item[product_additions][6][][quantity]"`

Comment: Try giving like this `params.require(:line_item).permit(:variant_id,product_additions: [:id,:quantity,:product_id])`

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70720/discussion-between-user177468-and-pavan).